# ¿Cómo elegir dígitos de entre ellos y usarlos para cálculos matemáticos,en secuencias de números extensas?

Tags: java, android, string

Tengo un `String` con un valor de número decimales como este:

```
<string name="action_settings">383612846295871194397861298498723456787809906342
```

y quiero tomar el caracter 5 y sumarlo con el caracter 16 ¿como lo hago?
en el caso de este `String` los valores serian: 1+1

//nota: el `String` no siempre tendrá los mismos valores, además acto seguido de esa suma sería sumar el resultado y restarlo el caracter final(en este caso 2)

Answer (score -2):

Sencillo buscar el caracter "5" en la cadena te da la posicion, lo poner en una variable y ejecutas la operacion que desees. Aqui te dejo varias maneras de hacerlo con su ejemplo. Te recomiendo el Libro: Absolute Java, fifth edition, by Walter Savitch; es excelente

String substring(Start, End) Returns the substring of the calling object string starting from position Start through, but not including, position End of the calling object. Positions are counted 0, 1, 2, etc. Be sure to notice that the character at position Start is included in the value returned, but the character at position End is not included. EXAMPLE After program executes String sample = "AbcdefG"; sample.substring(2, 5) returns "cde". int indexOf(A_String) Returns the index (position) of the first occurrence of the string A_String in the calling object string. Positions are counted 0, 1, 2, etc. Returns −1 if A_String is not found.

EXAMPLE After program executes String greeting = "Hi Mary!"; greeting.indexOf("Mary") returns 3, and greeting.indexOf("Sally") returns −1. int indexOf(A_String, Start) Returns the index (position) of the first occurrence of the string A_String in the calling object string that occurs at or after position Start. Positions are counted 0, 1, 2, etc. Returns −1 if A_String is not found.

EXAMPLE After program executes String name = "Mary, Mary quite contrary"; name.indexOf("Mary", 1) returns 6. The same value is returned if 1 is replaced by any number up to and including 6. name.indexOf("Mary", 0) returns 0. name.indexOf("Mary", 8) returns –1. int lastIndexOf(A_String) Returns the index (position) of the last occurrence of the string A_String in the calling object string. Positions are counted 0, 1, 2, etc. Returns −1, if A_String is not found.

EXAMPLE After program executes 
    String name = "Mary, Mary, Mary quite so"; greeting.indexOf("Mary") returns 0        name.lastIndexOf("Mary") returns 12.

Comment: Podrias mirar [answer]. Podrias traducir tu respuesta? ademas, como responde todo esto a la pregunta?